# How to get Cipher used by an HTTPS Connection

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

How do I get the Cipher used by an HTTPS Connection in Java? I need to find the TLS version used whether it's TLS 1.1 or 1.2 after hitting the URLusing the below code:

```
url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

Screenshot of the firefox browser is give below.
Can any one help me in getting this?
[TLS Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqu62.png)

I have tried

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) con.getSSLSocketFactory().createSocket();
String[] test = socket.getSSLParameters().getProtocols();
```

But this gives the list of protocols that are enabled for the connection. Where as I need the the protocol that was used in the response from the server.

The screenshot attached shows what I expecting to read(TLS 1.2)

Answer (score 2):

Call `HttpsURLConnection.getCipherSuite()`.

I earlier gave a longwinded answer that I now find is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'think `con.getCipherSuite();` should do the trick for algorithm...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

This could be an odd solution for tls but if you manage to open a new SSL socket(maybe then you can close with `socket.close();`) 
`SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) con.getSSLSocketFactory().createSocket();` `String[] test = socket.getSSLParameters().getProtocols();` In test value Notice that : You can get usable TLS versions not just only one.

Comment: Thanks, How can I get the TLS version also? As con.getCipherSuite() returns only TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. I need to get the TLS version as in this case it is 1.2. If TLS version would have been displayed I could have parsed it

Comment: This could be an odd solution but if you manage to open a new SSL socket(maybe then you can close) 
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) con.getSSLSocketFactory().createSocket();

      String[] test = socket.getSSLParameters().getProtocols();

In test value Notice that : You can get usable TLS versions not just only one.

Comment: SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) con.getSSLSocketFactory().createSocket(); String[] test = socket.getSSLParameters().getProtocols();  will give the list of Protocols that are enabled for the connection. But I need the one which is returned after opening the desired page.

Answer (score -1):

You can print the protocol (TLSv1.2) and suite (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES) with following:

```
SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("host", 443);
System.out.println("protocol: "+ss.getSession().getProtocol());
System.out.println("suite:    "+ss.getSession().ss.getSession().getCipherSuite());
```

Comment: You can get the TLS protocol of the new TLS session that got created when you created the new TLS connection. There is no guarantee that the session is the same, or the protocol..

Comment: @EJP indeed, you can get only the one which is current for the session. It can be renegotiated as well. And the browsers as well shows only "the current" session.

Comment: You can only get the one which is current for the current session, and there is no guarantee that that is correct for the *actual* session of interest. And you're also either leaking sockets or wasting extra connections.

Comment: @EJP this was only a snippet where to get the information. Nobody wants to open new connections.  If someone wants to pull this information to the URLConnection, using poolled connections there's no guarantee (neither that the connection won't be renegotiated)